# ActiveMQ and redelivery

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a question regarding re-delivery of messages.

The setup is as follows:

Two AMQ instances AMQ1 and AMQ2 (version 5.10.0) running in a master/slave configuration (where AMQ1 is master) and two consumers A and B fetching from the same queue Q. The clients are configured to use ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE and they sit in a loop fetching (pull mode) messages, *without* acknowledging any messages.

Test case:

1. Send a persistent message to the queue Q.
2. The message is consumed by A.
3. Stopping AMQ1, which brings AMQ2 up.

Now, one of two things happens:

a) Consumer A receives the message again which results in the message being put in the dead letter queue.
b) Consumer B receives the message and now both A and B has the same message.

In a) the problem I face is that if A crashes the message is lost. In b) the problem is that now two consumers act on the same message.

Is it possible to configure AMQ to somehow keep track of re-connecting consumers, so it won’t re-send a message if it discovers that it is already present at some consumer? At least there should be way in a) to avoid having the message put in the DLQ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're waiting to acknowledge your messages?  If you don't tell the broker you've processed the message, it's going to try to redeliver the message when it comes back up.  I'm surprised that you're seeing behavior a), but b) is very expected for what you're describing.

Comment: @Tim I'm processing messages that take minutes to complete. I will eventually acknowledge the message, but an AMQ restart during this processing will result in the test case described in my question.

Comment: OK, from your description it sounded like your consumers would pull a second (and third, fourth, etc.) message without acknowledging the first.  Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to configure ActiveMQ to resend a message if the client reconnects because the client restarted but not if the broker restarts or fails over.  Your best option may be to persist in your client the JMSMessageID for any messages you've processed but not ack'ed, so you can ignore the duplicates when they arrive a second time, which would address the problem in A.

You might be able to use [message groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html) to ensure that messages always go to the same consumer (preventing scenario B), but I've never used them myself so I'm not sure if they would apply across the two brokers in your failover scenario.  But it would be an easy test for you to do if you thought it might help.